# How to combine the usage of GetX and build_value?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-getx, built-value

Our app has a lot of provider (https://pub.dev/packages/provider) code which uses `built_value` (https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) to be able to work with immutable data objects.

Now we want to migrate the whole provider functionality to the state management of GetX (https://pub.dev/packages/get) but I am not clear about how to make these two things work together? GetX-controllers work with Rx-Values which are directly used in the logic part and whenever the value changes ONLY the listener gets notified which subscribed to exactly this value. But how does this work when it is combined with `built_value`? There the "actual" value is more or less hidden by an internal state which holds the data and can only access it indirect via getters.

So e.g. the actual data for a user only can be accessed in the `user` getter inside the `UserProviderState` like in the following example:

```
abstract class UserProviderState implements Built<UserProviderState, UserProviderStateBuilder> {
  User? get user;
  ...
}
```

An example for a GetX controller (without using `built_value`) is:

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  RxString username = ''.obs, password = ''.obs;
  RxBool obscurePassword = true.obs;
  ...
}
```

It is all a bit more nested when using `built_value` and some advice how to use it correctly with GetX would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`RxObject` notifies a listener when its value changes. 
I.e. (from docs):

```dart
final name = 'GetX'.obs;` 
// only "updates" the stream, if the value is different from the current one. 
name.value = 'Hey';
```

As `build_value` always return a new object you would always get a new value. 
So in order to trigger an update of your `RxObject` you just need to pass a new value to it:

```dart
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final state = UserProviderState().obs;
  ...
  void updateState() {
    state.value = state.value..someProperyOfState = 'new val';
  }
}
```

If you mean that you want replace `UserProviderState` with `GetxController` then, congratulations, you misused `built_value` and you need to move all those properties from there